# Unity - не перезагружается сцена

Tags: unity3d

Есть код:

```
public void ReloadScene() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene('1');
}
```

консоль выводит ошибку: Scene with build index 49 could't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings, хотя в Build Settings эта сцена у меня стоит. Что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если заменить апострофы на кавычки, заработает?
    SceneManager.LoadScene("1");

Comment: Воо, вот щас сработало! Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к комментарию, почему конкретно не сработал ваш код, и вы получили именно 49 в теле ошибки.

Посмотрите внимательно, на то какой параметр вы передаете в метод `LoadScene`. В вашем случае это `'1'` - это означает что вы передаете туда значение типа `char`.

Ищем в гугле по запросу - char value of 1. Получаем, например, [эту статью](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html), где написано, что значение ASCII у символа 1 - 049.

А теперь немного к документации юнити - [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) - принимает либо `int` - порядковый номер сцены в списке сцен, либо `string` - название сцены. В вашем случае нужно название сцены как строка. По этому исправьте параметр на

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("1");
```

Comment: Да, глупую ошибку допустил, спасибо